# How to grep same pattern of a sub string within a string in a large file?

Tags: python-3.x

In a file containing of fruits names as below:

```
file name : fruits.txt

-fruit apple -fruit- \
    -fruit orange -fruit- \
-fruit pear -fruit- \
    -fruit pear -fruit- -fruit pineapple -fruit- \
-fruit abcd apple efgh -fruit- -fruit jkl pear lkj -fruit- \
```

Remarks:
The reason of of using grepfunc.grep_iter because there will be really large file I need scan, then grepping out the name

Question:
How can I extract out all the fruit names in the file by using grep function module?

As the case in line 4 i only got the result of 'pineapple' as one sub string, but without the 1st fruit name 'pear'.

Another an example, the line 5 I got the result of 'jkl pear lkj', but not 'apple' as one sub string and 'pear' as another subs string.

Thus, the main problem that I facing now same line (with two fruit name)in a file cant grep the two fruit name out.

Here's the coding I tried,

```
import grepfunc

fruit_array = []
file1 = open('fruits.txt', 'r')
for fruit_name in grepfunc.grep_iter(file1, ".*-fruit"):
    fruit_name = re.sub(r'^.*-fruit ', '', fruit_name)
    fruit_name = re.sub(r' -fruit-.*$', '', fruit_name)
    fruit_array.append(fruit_name)
    print(fruit_name)
```

Expectation Results:
fruit_array = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'apple', 'pear']

Real Results:
fruit_array = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'pineapple', 'jkl pear lkj']

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can tolerate reading the entire `fruit.txt` file into memory, in Python, you may use `re.findall` with the pattern `-fruit (\S+)`:

```
inp = """-fruit apple -fruit- \
-fruit orange -fruit- \
    -fruit pear -fruit- \
    -fruit pear -fruit- -fruit pineapple -fruit- \ """
fruits = re.findall(r'-fruit (\S+)', inp)
print(fruits)
```

This prints:

```
['apple', 'orange', 'pear', 'pear', 'pineapple']
```

Comment: Hi Tim, maybe my question is not clear enough. Actually, the file contents is quite big and the pattern not just -fruit (fruit name) -fruit-. There are still some unwanted string within the pattern. For an example, there will be a line in the file containing -fruit abcd apple efgh -fruit- -fruit jkl pear lkj -fruit- \. The part i most concerning about is using a right regex in the grepfunc.grep_iter(), so i can achieve the extracting of fruit name in a large file.

Comment: @Chaos My answer as given would work for the sample input in your comment, because it would only capture non whitespace content after `-fruit`.

Comment: Do you mean take r'-fruit (\S+)' as the argument for the iterator function? Like this `for fruit_name in grepfunc.grep_iter(file1, r'-fruit (\S+)'):`?

Comment: Please edit your question with input data for which my current answer would _not_ already work.  I'm happy to edit if necessary.

Comment: Hi Tim, i made the edit. Please help me have a look on my question again. Thanks.

Comment: You can't really handle the updated input without a priori knowing what the matching fruit names are.